# Android Studio: Can't make new project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-7

I recently refreshed my laptop. After the refresh I had to install all my applications again. I downloaded Android Studio, Android SDK and JDK 7 and installed them.

I created an environment variable `JAVA_HOME` with `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`.

But whenever I open Android Studio I can't create a new project or even open an old one. I click on create new project, then fill in the necessary details. Then I click on finish and it goes back to the quick start dialog box which I started off with (create new project dialog box).

I have read similar questions like this asked on Stack Overflow and they all say to set the `java_home` variable.

NOTE: I have also tried `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\`.

Comment: Yeah sure. I click on create new project, then fill in the necessary details. Then I click on finish and it goes back to the quick start dialog box which I started off with (create new project dialog box).

Comment: Have you added `JAVA_HOME\bin` to the `PATH`?

Comment: No. What is JAVA_HOME\bin?

Comment: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is what you should add to `PATH` of your environment variables on `Windows`

Comment: Yes I have done that. Still no success..